# Adding arguments to a piece of \tikzset code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please look at the following piece of code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MOBILE TOWER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\MBS}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[station] (base) {#1};

%\draw[line join=bevel] (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east) -- cycle;
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.80) -- (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east);
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.70) (base.110) -- (base.north east);

% original yshift=.8pt
%\draw[line cap=rect] ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=.3pt] base.north) [antenna=1];
%\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.3pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- node[above,shape=rectangle,inner ysep=+.3333em]{\dots} ([xshift=-.5cm,yshift=.3pt]base.north) [antenna=2];
\draw[line cap=rect] ([xshift=-.1768cm,yshift=.6pt]base.north -| base.right tail) [antenna=1];
\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.6pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- node[above,shape=rectangle,inner ysep=+.3333em]{\dots} ([xshift=.1768cm,yshift=.6pt]base.north -| base.left tail) [antenna=2];

%\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.3pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- ([xshift=-.5cm,yshift=.3pt]base.north) [antenna=2];
%\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

It allows me to write commands like

```
\draw (-4,0) node[scale=2]{\MBS{a}} ;
```

and generate a figure with a label 'a' in its centre (In wireless communications, this diagram sort of refers to a mobile tower). Now the following piece of code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RELAY %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment length=4pt}}},
         relay/.pic={
        code={\tikzset{scale=5/10}
            \draw[semithick] (0,0) -- (1,4);% left line
            \draw[semithick] (3,0) -- (2,4);% right line
            \draw[semithick] (0,0) arc (180:0:1.5 and -0.5);
            \node[inner sep=4pt] (circ) at (1.5,5.5) {};
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,5.5) circle(8pt);
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,5.5cm-8pt) -- (1.5,4);
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,4) ellipse (0.5 and 0.166);
            \draw[semithick,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] (1.5cm+8pt,5.5) -- +(0:2);
            \draw[semithick,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] (1.5cm-8pt,5.5) -- +(180:2);
  }}
}
```

allows me to write code like

```
\path (2,-1.2)  pic[scale=0.5,color=red] {relay};
```

which generates a figure without a label at its center (For the curious, it is referred to as a relay in wireless communications). How do I achieve that custom labeling in the center similar to the first example (mobile tower).

A full working example is given in the following code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usepackage{ellipsis}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{naming/.style={align=center,font=\small}}
\tikzset{antenna/.style={insert path={-- coordinate (ant#1) ++(0,0.25) -- +(135:0.25) + (0,0) -- +(45:0.25)}}}
\tikzset{station/.style={naming,draw,shape=dart,shape border rotate=90, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=10mm,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt}}
%\tikzset{mobile/.style={naming,draw,shape=rectangle,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=7.5mm, outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt}}
\tikzset{mobile/.style={naming,draw,shape=rectangle,minimum width=12mm,minimum height=6mm, outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt}}
%\tikzset{radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment length=4pt}}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RELAY %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment length=4pt}}},
         relay/.pic={
        code={\tikzset{scale=5/10}
            \draw[semithick] (0,0) -- (1,4);% left line
            \draw[semithick] (3,0) -- (2,4);% right line
            \draw[semithick] (0,0) arc (180:0:1.5 and -0.5);
            \node[inner sep=4pt] (circ) at (1.5,5.5) {};
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,5.5) circle(8pt);
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,5.5cm-8pt) -- (1.5,4);
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,4) ellipse (0.5 and 0.166);
            \draw[semithick,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] (1.5cm+8pt,5.5) -- +(0:2);
            \draw[semithick,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] (1.5cm-8pt,5.5) -- +(180:2);
  }}
}

%%%%%%%%% MOBILE PHONE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\UE}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={rectangle,minimum width=0pt}]
\node[mobile] (box) {#1};

\draw ([xshift=.25cm] box.south west) circle (4pt)
      ([xshift=-.25cm]box.south east) circle (4pt);

\fill ([xshift=.25cm] box.south west) circle (1pt)
      ([xshift=-.25cm]box.south east) circle (1pt);

\draw (box.north) [antenna=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MOBILE BASE STATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\MBS}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[station] (base) {#1};

%\draw[line join=bevel] (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east) -- cycle;
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.80) -- (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east);
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.70) (base.110) -- (base.north east);

% original yshift=.8pt
%\draw[line cap=rect] ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=.3pt] base.north) [antenna=1];
%\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.3pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- node[above,shape=rectangle,inner ysep=+.3333em]{\dots} ([xshift=-.5cm,yshift=.3pt]base.north) [antenna=2];
\draw[line cap=rect] ([xshift=-.1768cm,yshift=.6pt]base.north -| base.right tail) [antenna=1];
\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.6pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- node[above,shape=rectangle,inner ysep=+.3333em]{\dots} ([xshift=.1768cm,yshift=.6pt]base.north -| base.left tail) [antenna=2];

%\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.3pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- ([xshift=-.5cm,yshift=.3pt]base.north) [antenna=2];
%\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DIAGRAM STARTS HERE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[every path/.append style={thick}]
\draw (-4,0) ellipse (8 and 3);
\draw (8,0) ellipse (8 and 3);

\draw (-4,0) node[scale=2]{\MBS{a}} ;
\draw (8,0) node[scale=2,color=red]{\MBS{2}} ;
\path (2,1)  pic[scale=0.5,color=red] {relay};
\path (2,-1.2)  pic[scale=0.5,color=red] {relay};
\draw (1,0) node[scale=.8]{\UE{1}};
\draw (-1,0) node[scale=.8]{\UE{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide a complete working example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` with all libraries and definitions. You first code doesn't work because `station` is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}


\tikzset{radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment length=4pt}}},
         relay/.pic={
        code={\tikzset{scale=5/10}
            \draw[semithick] (0,0) -- (1,4);% left line
            \draw[semithick] (3,0) -- (2,4);% right line
            \draw[semithick] (0,0) arc (180:0:1.5 and -0.5) node[above, midway]{#1};
            \node[inner sep=4pt] (circ) at (1.5,5.5) {};
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,5.5) circle(8pt);
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,5.5cm-8pt) -- (1.5,4);
            \draw[semithick] (1.5,4) ellipse (0.5 and 0.166);
            \draw[semithick,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] (1.5cm+8pt,5.5) -- +(0:2);
            \draw[semithick,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] (1.5cm-8pt,5.5) -- +(180:2);
  }}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2,-1.2)  pic[scale=0.5,color=red] {relay=B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I change the scale, the font scale doesn't change.

Comment: @dineshdileep By default, font size is not affected with scale factors. You can change this behavior applying `transform shape` option to those nodes where you want to change it.

Comment: How do I do that in the above code? I added "tranform shape" to both \tikzset code and in the code between \begin{document}\end{document}. But it is not working. My tikz skills are at beginner level. I apologize.

Comment: @dineshdileep `node[transform shape, above, midway]{#1}` That's all. But remember that a previous `scale=5/10` has been already applied when watching results.

Comment: I changed that to scale=10/10. But not giving satisfactory results. Is there a way to scale the font alone?

Comment: @dineshdileep You can use `font` or `node font` options to fix font size. Page 221 in pgfmanual.